# Property 'closeTo' does not exist on type 'Expect'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

```
test('compare float in object properties', () => {
  expect({
    title: '0.1 + 0.2',
    sum: 0.1 + 0.2,
  }).toEqual({
    title: '0.1 + 0.2',
    sum: expect.closeTo(0.3, 5),
  });
});
```

> Property 'closeTo' does not exist on type 'Expect'.

Why am I getting this error ?

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd ensure `@types/jest` has the same version as `jest` package does.

As a last resort, you can extend type definition as we [do for custom matchers](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers):

```
interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  closeTo(delta: number, value: number): R;
}

declare global {
  namespace jest {
    interface Expect extends CustomMatchers {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried downgrading `jest` from 27.5.1 to 27.4.1 -- the version `@types/jest` reportedly is on.  That had no effect.  Upgrading `@types.jest` is not possible (yet, presumably).

I did extend the type definition as you suggested, and that works (but feels like a hack...)

Comment: hack indeed, but I'd not consider this as a big deal